# Open an Excel File on Sharepoint from SSIS Package without moving it

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, ssis

I'm trying to change some Excel Files which are laying on SharePoint. 
This should be performed automatically while my Import to SQL-Server is running. For the Import I'm using a SSIS.

Is it possible to change Excel Files with SSIS? And hwo is it possible? 
By the way the SSIS package should open and close the the Excel files so that I got no interferences through open packages.

I'm Using Excel 2013, SQL-Server and Visual Studio 2013

Comment: If in sharepoint you go to library->open with explorer it will give you the path to those files. I guess you could access to them with SSIS using that path (never use it, but it's worth a try)

Comment: Yeah the path is not the problem. I have no idea how to Adresse this this files from SSIS. So I know I Need a scriptable task but I don't know how to configure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to open Excel-Files on SharePoint:

`Dim process As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
 process.Start("filepath")
 process.Close()`

If you get the Excel- File as .xlsm file you can directly process the macro. If you get an .xlsx- file you need to make an extra file which can process macros and then you process the new file.